# i am trying to achieve functionality of not deleting a calendar event in odoo how can i avoid the following scenario?

Tags: python, calendar, odoo, odoo-8

I have inherited calendar.event and have written the following custom unlink function

```
class calendar_event(osv.osv):

    _inherit = "calendar.event"
    _rec_name = 'number'
    _columns = {
            'number' : fields.char('Meeting ID',readonly=1),
            }

    '''_defaults = {
                'number' : lambda self,cr,uid,context={}:self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr,uid,'calendar.event'),
                }'''

    def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
         group_pool = self.pool.get('res.groups')
         group_id = group_pool.search(cr, uid, [('name','=','Delete Calendar'),('users.id','=',uid)])
         if group_id: 
            return super(osv.osv, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
         else:
            raise osv.except_osv('Error', 'You cannot delete this Calendar, Please contact Admin...')

         return True
```

Now this function has its super unlink function as below which is in calendar.event

```
def unlink(self, cr, uid, ids, can_be_deleted=True, context=None):
        if not isinstance(ids, list):
            ids = [ids]
        res = False

        ids_to_exclure = []
        ids_to_unlink = []

        for event_id in ids:
            if can_be_deleted and len(str(event_id).split('-')) == 1:  # if  ID REAL
                if self.browse(cr, uid, int(event_id), context).recurrent_id:
                    ids_to_exclure.append(event_id)
                else:
                    ids_to_unlink.append(int(event_id))
            else:
                ids_to_exclure.append(event_id)

        if ids_to_unlink:
            res = super(calendar_event, self).unlink(cr, uid, ids_to_unlink, context=context)

        if ids_to_exclure:
            for id_to_exclure in ids_to_exclure:
                res = self.write(cr, uid, id_to_exclure, {'active': False}, context=context)

        return res
```

Now when things happen, i am getting the following error:

```
unlink() got an unexpected keyword argument 'can_be_deleted'
```

Anyone have any idea to overcome this problem,

Comment: and it is also linked to google_calendar.py's unlink function making it more complex. :(